# R subset custom function with optional wildcard param

Tags: r

I want to write an R function with some optional params. It should subset some data by two core params and then I want to have the option to pass additional constraints. Eg.

```
filter_func <- function(start_datetime, end_datetime, user=*, type=*){
  as.data.frame(subset(df, format(df$datetime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") > start_datetime &
                           format(df$datetime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") < end_datetime) &
                           df$user == user &
                           df$type == type)
```

So... if i pass a param it constrains it to that column on either user or type, but if i don't it uses the wildcard and gets everything in the column?

I've seen examples here that use `%in%` or `grepl()` but those seem more aimed at where you have part of a string and then want the rest... like `new_york` gets both `new_york_city` and `new_york_state`... i don't want to get any values that don't exactly match the param!

**edit: now with examples**

So... ideally go from something like this...

```
   start         |        end       | user | type |
-----------------|------------------|------|------|
2017-01-01 11:00 | 2017-01-01 20:00 | usr1 | typ1 |
2017-01-01 12:00 | 2017-01-01 19:00 | usr2 | typ2 |
2017-01-01 02:00 | 2017-01-01 03:00 | usr2 | typ1 |
2017-03-01 01:00 | 2017-03-01 09:00 | usr1 | typ2 |
2017-04-01 05:00 | 2017-04-01 07:00 | usr3 | typ4 |
2017-05-01 01:00 | 2017-05-01 08:00 | usr2 | typ5 |
```

use my function `filter_func(2017-01-01 00:00, 2017-01-01 23:59)`

gets me:

```
   start         |        end       | user | type |
-----------------|------------------|------|------|
2017-01-01 11:00 | 2017-01-01 20:00 | usr1 | typ1 |
2017-01-01 12:00 | 2017-01-01 19:00 | usr2 | typ2 |
2017-01-01 02:00 | 2017-01-01 03:00 | usr2 | typ1 |
```

but if i add a param `filter_func(2017-01-01 00:00, 2017-01-01 23:59, usr2)`

```
   start         |        end       | user | type |
-----------------|------------------|------|------|
2017-01-01 12:00 | 2017-01-01 19:00 | usr2 | typ2 |
2017-01-01 02:00 | 2017-01-01 03:00 | usr2 | typ1 |
```

or even `filter_func(2017-01-01 00:00, 2017-01-01 23:59, usr2, typ2)`

```
   start         |        end       | user | type |
-----------------|------------------|------|------|
2017-01-01 12:00 | 2017-01-01 19:00 | usr2 | typ2 |
```

Comment: Use the word boundary i.e. `\\b` at the end

Comment: possibly will help to see sample data and expected results

Comment: @akrun , could you provide a bit more of an example? As in I'd do `user='\\b'`?

Comment: a. `subset` is designed to be used interactively, not programmatically. `[` is less likely to cause problems. b. `format` is a bad idea here; you're now comparing strings instead of datetimes, which may not work the way you think. Better to use `as.POSIXct` or the like. c. You could use control flow like `if` if you break your subsetting into parts, storing the intermediate result.

Comment: ah ha, thank you @alistaire - if you would be willing to provide an example (doesn't necessarily have to solve my problem above) of combined `[if x]` syntax, i'd be happy to mark your answer as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,

- `[` is safer for programmatic use than `subset`.
- You don't need `format`, which turns datetime objects into string; you need `as.POSIXct` or the like, which parse strings into datetimes. You could do this in the function, but you *should* do this before the function, as you'll always want your datetimes parsed, and there's no point in doing it repeatedly.
- You can update a version of the data.frame internal to the function in several steps, which allows you to use control flow like `if`. You'll still need to check if the variable exists. Two options:

  - Use `missing`, which is built for checking whether function parameters exist.
  - Supply a default value of `NULL` and use `is.null`.
- You'll need to pass in quoted strings or parsed datetimes (`<` operators will try to coerce objects that don't match to the same class).
- I added a parameter to pass in the data.frame first, which gives the function broader use, but is not necessary.

Altogether, then,

```r
df <- data.frame(start = c("2017-01-01 11:00", "2017-01-01 12:00", "2017-01-01 02:00", 
                           "2017-03-01 01:00", "2017-04-01 05:00", "2017-05-01 01:00"),
                 end = c("2017-01-01 20:00", "2017-01-01 19:00", "2017-01-01 03:00", 
                         "2017-03-01 09:00", "2017-04-01 07:00", "2017-05-01 08:00"),
                 user = c("usr1", "usr2", "usr2", "usr1", "usr3", "usr2"),
                 type = c( "typ1", "typ2", "typ1", "typ2", "typ4", "typ5"))

# parse in two steps if you like, e.g. df$start <- as.POSIXct(df$start)
df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], as.POSIXct)

filter_func <- function(x, start_time, end_time, usr, typ = NULL){
    x <- x[x$start > start_time & x$end < end_time, ]
    if (!missing(usr)) {
      x <- x[x$user %in% usr, ]
    }
    if (!is.null(typ)) {
      x <- x[x$type %in% typ, ]
    }
    x
}
```

and test it:

```r
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ start: POSIXct, format: "2017-01-01 11:00:00" "2017-01-01 12:00:00" ...
#>  $ end  : POSIXct, format: "2017-01-01 20:00:00" "2017-01-01 19:00:00" ...
#>  $ user : Factor w/ 3 levels "usr1","usr2",..: 1 2 2 1 3 2
#>  $ type : Factor w/ 4 levels "typ1","typ2",..: 1 2 1 2 3 4

filter_func(df, as.POSIXct('2017-01-01 00:00'), as.POSIXct('2017-01-01 23:59'))
#>                 start                 end user type
#> 1 2017-01-01 11:00:00 2017-01-01 20:00:00 usr1 typ1
#> 2 2017-01-01 12:00:00 2017-01-01 19:00:00 usr2 typ2
#> 3 2017-01-01 02:00:00 2017-01-01 03:00:00 usr2 typ1

filter_func(df, '2017-01-01 00:00', '2017-01-01 23:59')
#>                 start                 end user type
#> 1 2017-01-01 11:00:00 2017-01-01 20:00:00 usr1 typ1
#> 2 2017-01-01 12:00:00 2017-01-01 19:00:00 usr2 typ2
#> 3 2017-01-01 02:00:00 2017-01-01 03:00:00 usr2 typ1

filter_func(df, '2017-01-01 00:00', '2017-01-01 23:59', 'usr2')
#>                 start                 end user type
#> 2 2017-01-01 12:00:00 2017-01-01 19:00:00 usr2 typ2
#> 3 2017-01-01 02:00:00 2017-01-01 03:00:00 usr2 typ1

filter_func(df, '2017-01-01 00:00', '2017-01-01 23:59', 'usr2', 'typ2')
#>                 start                 end user type
#> 2 2017-01-01 12:00:00 2017-01-01 19:00:00 usr2 typ2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `grepl()` for pattern matching.

```
filter_func <- function(start_datetime, end_datetime, user_='*', type_='*'){
    subset(df, as.POSIXlt(df$start) > as.POSIXlt(start_datetime) &
                             as.POSIXlt(df$end) < as.POSIXlt(end_datetime) &
                            grepl(user_, df$user) &
                            grepl(type_, df$type))
}

filter_func(start='2017-01-01 00:00', end='2017-01-01 23:59')
#            start              end user type
#1 2017-01-01 11:00 2017-01-01 20:00 usr1 typ1
#2 2017-01-01 12:00 2017-01-01 19:00 usr2 typ2
#3 2017-01-01 02:00 2017-01-01 03:00 usr2 typ1

filter_func(start='2017-01-01 00:00', end='2017-01-01 23:59', user='usr2')
#            start              end user type
#2 2017-01-01 12:00 2017-01-01 19:00 usr2 typ2
#3 2017-01-01 02:00 2017-01-01 03:00 usr2 typ1

filter_func(start='2017-01-01 00:00', end='2017-01-01 23:59', user='usr2', type='typ2')
#            start              end  user type
#2 2017-01-01 12:00 2017-01-01 19:00 usr2 typ2
```